# Best way to clone observables?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What is the best way to clone Observable objects in Knockout to make kind of transactions mechanism?
For example editing this model:

```
var Action = function (name, ownerType, condition, expression, args) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.ownerType = ko.observable(ownerType);
    this.condition = ko.observable(condition);
    this.expression = ko.observable(expression);
    this.args = ko.observable(args);
};
```

I want to save state of that object before user will edit it. And if user will cancel editing - rollback object state.
Simplest way is just create another project like:

```
self.tempAction = new Action(action.name(), action.ownerType(), action.condition(), action.expression(), action.args());
```

But I'm not sure that it is elegant solution..

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually do something like the following:

First I have a function that mimics jQuery's `$.extend` function. It populates a `target` object with all of the `observable` (or non-observable) property values of the `source` object.

```
// extends observable objects intelligently
ko.utils.extendObservable = function ( target, source ) {
    var prop, srcVal, isObservable = false;

    for ( prop in source ) {

        if ( !source.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( ko.isWriteableObservable( source[prop] ) ) {
            isObservable = true;
            srcVal = source[prop]();
        } else if ( typeof ( source[prop] ) !== 'function' ) {
            srcVal = source[prop];
        }

        if ( ko.isWriteableObservable( target[prop] ) ) {
            target[prop]( srcVal );
        } else if ( target[prop] === null || target[prop] === undefined ) {

            target[prop] = isObservable ? ko.observable( srcVal ) : srcVal;

        } else if ( typeof ( target[prop] ) !== 'function' ) {
            target[prop] = srcVal;
        }

        isObservable = false;
    }
    return target;
};
```

Then I have a `copy` function that essentially converts the object to be copied into `JSON` and then takes the `JSON` copy and builds a new javascript object. This ensures all the memory pointers are not copied and you have a brand new object that matches your original one. The one key here is that you do have to pass in an empty instance of a new object (otherwise we would have no idea what properties to populate)

```
// then finally the clone function
ko.utils.clone = function(obj, emptyObj){
    var json = ko.toJSON(obj);
    var js = JSON.parse(json);

    return ko.utils.extendObservable(emptyObj, js);
};
```

You can then use it like so:

```
var tempAction = ko.utils.clone(action, new Action());
```

Comment: Could you not just use the ko.mapping plugin to map from the original source object to the new target object?

Comment: @jaffa - yes, the mapping plugin would be a suitable option. However it can be overkill for trivial needs. Also, I've found the `extendObservable` function quite useful in situations where the mapping plugin wasn't needed application wide.

Comment: How does this work with ko.computed values? I would think using toJSON and JSON.parse to copy an object will lose all its computed values.

Comment: @ericb +1 Works, but it seems like overkill, I have similar method as yours extendObservable and for some reason I can't get it to work by passing empty instance and copying original object without serializing original instance to JSON first, do have a clue why is that, I mean, what references stick since you are unwrapping observable to get to pure value...?

Comment: There maybe some questions in deep clone, I mean nested viewModels.